# assign a value to variable using url return method in Ext JS

Tags: c#, extjs

In stores ,i've used
`store_Employees.getProxy().url='Services/..../...';` method for  loading the store.
In the same way, I want a variable x to have some value which is returned from a  Services file(through Url).
Can someone suggest how it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use Ext.Ajax to achieve that, like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'YourUrl',

    params: {       
        some_param: 'some_value'
    },

    success: function(response, opts) {     

        //Horay, Do something with the response

    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {

        //Oh nooooo
    }
});
```

Ext docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Ajax.html

Comment: Hi, when i use   `var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText); `
 in success function, it is returning total method name and value. but i need only value. 
please help me in that.
In my Case the result is `DetailsCheckResult: 1` but i need the result to be only  `1`.

Comment: Without seeing an example of your code is difficult to help with a concrete solution. Follow the example of Fabio Barros and in success: function create a console.log (response). At the DevTools console try to find where your DetailsCheckResult:1 object is. Then test with the all path; for example console.log (response.something.DetailsCheckResult);

Comment: I got it, i've used
`var result = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.DetailsCheckResult);` 
`result.message` returned value

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting after an AJAX request is JSON, JSON is an object you cannot simply get the value of the object.

Comment: I have used JQuery.parseJSON method and it returned value.